# Hide <header> if in iFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe, tumblr

I'm trying to hide the header of my tumblr-blog, in case the blog is loaded in an iFrame. But so far I didn't have any success. This is what I'm using as a code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location);
   if(isInIFrame==true){
       alert("It's in an iFrame");
       document.getElementById('boven').hide();
       }
   else {
       alert("It's NOT in an iFrame");
       }
</script>
```

and I've the part I want to hide like this: `<header id="boven"></header>`

I've searched and tried different things, but it doesn't seem to start working. I do get the  `alert();` in true and false, but it doesn't want to hide…

I hope someone can help me out, I'd be very grateful. So thanks in advance!

Comment: where you have this `boven` element? inside iFrame or parent? where you execute this js code?

Comment: and are you sure `hide()` works ? I see no sign of jQuery or other framework here, but maybe you implemented this method yourself ?

Comment: Not that it matters, but a better check would probably be `(window !== window.parent)`

Answer (score 4):

There is no `hide()` function on any native DOM element that I know of. In plain JavaScript, you can hide an element by altering it's "display" mode:

```
document.getElementById('boven').style.display = "none";
```

In a UI library such as jQuery, a `hide()` method may be available. Here's the equivalent in jQuery syntax:

```
$('#boven').hide();
```

If you use a debugging tool such as the Chrome Console, Firebug in Firefox, or F12 Development Tools in IE, you would have found out right away that there is no such method `hide()` on a `<header>` element.